# Could "curved" be the opposite of "flat"?

Tags: nouns, antonyms

What is the opposite of flat? and is it curved?

e.g.

- the tabletop is flat
- the tabletop is (not flat or curved).

In other examples could curved be the opposite?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [what is the opposite of the word 'flat'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41518/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-word-flat)  (In particular, look at @J.R. 's answer, which was composed before the original poster mentioned that he was describing fungus colonies.)

Comment: I am retracting my close vote, because J.R.'s list does not specifically include "curved."  Still read it, though.

Comment: No close votes on this one! Dicts don't say it that simply, so please don't close this blindfoldedly!

Answer (score 1):

*Curved* and *flat* can be direct antonyms in certain cases, but they usually aren't.

As related to a tabletop, the proper antonym would be *uneven*, not *curved*, because tabletops are *flat* by definition. A *curved table* would mean that the tabletop is not rectangular or oval in shape, or that it has rounded edges. Something similar to a table but with a vertically curved surface would be a *basin* or perhaps a *bowl* or *dish*.

In mathematics, one can use *curved* and *flat* as antonyms for describing the slope or rate of change of the graphs of functions (which are generally called *curves*). [Here's an example on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6313/74987) suggesting *flat* and *curved* as antonyms in the context of *learning curve*.

Outside of technical ones, I can't think of any cases where *curved* and *flat* are properly used as antonyms.

Comment: Describing the horizon as you gain altitude?

Answer (score 1):

*Flat* has [many antonyms](//ell.stackexchange.com/q/41518/5289), one of which is *curved*.  Example:

> #### [Are curved TVs any better than flat TVs?](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2014/07/are-curved-tvs-any-better-than-flat-screen-tvs/index.htm)
>
> After years of pushing ever-flatter, thinner TVs, manufacturers are
>   throwing buyers a curve—literally, with curved-screen sets. …

Answer (score 1):

If the table top is unintentionally not flat, I'd probably say that it is "warped".